# how to capture 802.11 packets in Windows 10 using Wireshark?

Tags: windows, wireshark, wifi

I'm investigating why in my Wireshark, I can't get any WLAN packets such as WPS, WPA and so on. Actually, any of the wlan filters, in order to filter by SSID or MAC, works. In Wireshark, in the WiFi interface, if I go to details, I see that the 802.11 WLAN option is disabled so there is no 802.11 WLAN traffic captures.

However, by investigating my PC drivers, apparently there is one driver that does it. This is the Intel (R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 which is the driver used in my WiFi interface.

I thought in the wireshark options, the 802.11 WLAN traffic should appear too, but it doesn't! I saw some people who also have the Driver Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter but I'm not sure if I can install it because my PC may not have the Broadcom chip.

Is there anyone using Windows 10 that can get 802.11 packets? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.  Probably the easiest and cheapest way is to uninstall [WinPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/) and install [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/).  There are other ways too though, such as by purchasing an [AirPcap adapter](https://www.riverbed.com/products/steelcentral/steelcentral-riverbed-airpcap.html) from Riverbed.

Refer to the [Windows section of the Wireshark CaptureSetup/WLAN wiki page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Windows) for more information.

Comment: thank you! I did that but I think my NIC can't capture packets in monitor mode, so instead of getting an AirPcap adapter, I was thinking to go for a cheaper option such as this: https://www.netgear.es/support/product/a6200.aspx I hope this works!